# Gauss' law: Infinitely long cylinder approximation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law, approximations

Why approximating a cylinder as infinitely long works when $R << L$? 
Where $R$ is the radius and $L$ is the length of the cylinder.

I was able to prove for a line of charges when r << L (Where r is the distance from the line ) and we choose a point close to the middle, The difference in length between the middle point and the ends doesn't matter if the condition r << L applies (Because of inverse tan function) and I can assume the same works for the thin cylinder because it is made out of line of charges.

But when logically thinking about it, if we have a finite rod and we move from the middle point then we don't have symmetry anymore and if we reduce r the contribution from the longer end should get larger because the distance to the point is less and horizontal component is larger. Why the contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, mathematically you have seen it works, and that's nice. Now you have to think **physically**.

Since we are talking about "continuous" functions and non-chaotic systems, a slightly different initial condition shouldn't affect the solution too much.

In physics, one must have **scales** always in mind. Numbers alone don't mean anything, it's all about comparison. Is 15 Joules of energy much or not? **it all depends** on the scale of your problem. It's nothing for the Sun, but so over the top for an atom.

Let's go to your particular case. What is infinite? Discard the mathematicall definition right now: in physics, infinite means just "really big".

A purist outsider would say that "really long" is not strictly infinite, but we do, and it works! That's the matter after all.

See it this way: for a flea, a radio antenna might be infinite. It's true, it is finite, but the flea will rarely be able to tell. That's what it is about.

If you're on the center, you see infinitely long wire at both sides (it's actually finite, but you just see "extremely long", you don't see the end). If you move a little, you'll still see "extremely long" at both sides. (It's okay, one side is shorter now, but the difference is so small compared to the lenght that you can't tell). If you're on the center of a table, would you be abel to tell if someone has cut off 1mm of the left side? Probably not. So you're seeing almost the same problem, so it should have the same solution.

This is a very good approximation. Experimental differencies are namesd **edge effects**, because it 's like "if there were no edges (infinite), it would be like my model, but there's an edge that disturbs the result a little bit.

So it's all about scales. Something is infinite if it is "so much big". And What exactly is "big"? It depends on the scale of your problem. We usually set "big" as two orders of magnitude (100) times more, or even more. 100 is a reference, but it's not so much precision. Many people set at least $10^3$.

If your table is $1m$ long and you take out less than 1mm, would you notice? I don't think so. So you're seeing mostly the same system $\Rightarrow$ you'll find the same solution.

In Lab, you must see if your error scale is small enough compared to the reference. IF so, you can apply this approximation, and it works very well. Some problems are irresoluble without approximations, so do not feel bad for using them ever. Physics work with models so that we can measure things, you'll never want to know magnitudes with 200 decimal places ;)